# Is Multivariate Regression right for my study?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to plan the following experiment;

I am examining the perceptual effects of a tutor’s voice on distance learning students and their evaluation of the course.

My SV is ‘perceived voice pleseantness’; distance learning students rate a tutors voice on a scale of 1 - 5, 1 = very unpleasant 5 = very pleasant.

The DV’s I would like to use (to help me link it to a previous study) are;

1. Learning outcome (module mark)
2. Motivation
3. Satisfaction
4. Perceived expertise

My teacher has recommended I carry out multivariate regression anaysis to get my answers.

Please can someone explain to me why I can't just do a MANOVA in this situation? I haven't learned multivariate regression yet so I'm struggling with this.

I'm also using SPSS, I have read it is not possible to do this analysis in SPSS, is this correct?

Comment: Do you want to use Learning outcome (module mark), Motivation ,Satisfaction, Perceived expertise as dependent variables, I mean take them all as dependent variables?

Comment: There must be a bit more clarification about the problem to answer the question and please post the reference to the dataset if possible

Comment: Yes Erik, they will all be dependent variables. I don't have a data set, I just need to design this experiment for university.

Comment: If this is a work for a class or something like that, please read the description of the tag [tag:self-study] and add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by the recommendation to do multivariate regression. That would be appropriate if your independent/predictor variable were continuous, but yours only has 5 levels. It might be appropriate if you thought that each step along the "perceived voice pleasantness" scale was likely to have the same influence on outcomes, but there's no way to know that a priori. So on that basis I don't see why multivariate regression would be preferred to multivariate ANOVA.

That said, the basic concept is the same for either, in that the analysis considers the correlation structure among your dependent/outcome variables. So if you are comfortable with MANOVA, the extension to multivariate regression shouldn't be too much of a conceptual stretch. If this is work for a class, the reasons for choosing multivariate regression over MANOVA and how to implement the multivariate regression would seem to be an issue to discuss with your teacher.

One potential problem with your design is that the independent variable might not be "independent"; for example, someone who did poorly or didn't like the course might simply tend to rate the tutor's voice more unfavorably as a result, so that you could have the inferred causality backwards. In that case looking at the correlation structures as @user25459 suggested might be appropriate, instead of either multiple regression or MANOVA.

Answer (score 0):

Your proper test statistic should be Somers' D, based on how I understand your scales.  I think your professor has misunderstood that your four variables are predicted by the fifth. That requires either using Somers' D as a measure of correlation or a probit model, each done four times.

Since you have yet to learn multivariate regression, probit is way out of sight for you, but Somers' D is not.

Somers' D is an asymmetric measure of association among two variables.  This differs from Spearman's rho, which is a symmetric measure, by how it handles tied observations.

Consider the two statements, "if it is raining, then it is cloudy," and "if it is cloudy, then it is raining."  Under Spearman's rho, these are equivalent statements because it is symmetric.  If it is correlated in one direction, then it is equally correlated in the other.

Under Somers' D, the correlation for the first statement would be 1 because if water is falling from the sky then there is a cloud up there.  In the other direction it would have a much lower level of association, probably equal to the percentage of time that it rains when it is cloudy.  Let's set an imaginary correlation of 0.30.  Spearman's rho might be 0.40.

Now you will have to make adjustments because there are four hypotheses tests without a master F test to cover them.  So you would do the Holm-Bonferroni correction to eliminate spurious significance.  Its not the only way to make the correction, but it is reasonable for what you are doing.